# Show that a washer is open in the complex field

Tags: complex-analysis

$$D=\left\{z\ \left|\ \right. 1<|z|<2, \ \Re(z)>-\frac{1}{2}\right\}$$

I can try to prove that each disc with radius 1, and 2 is open (?), so I need to show that the ball centered at $w$ is contained in the disc with radius 2

If $w\in \{z: |z|<2\}$, then $|z_0-w|<2$, let $\epsilon = 2-|z_0-w|>0$

Let $z\in \mathbb{C}$, such that $|z-w|<\epsilon$

and $|z-z_0|\leq |z-w|+|z_0-w|<2$, so the ball of radius $\epsilon$ is contained inside the disc with radius $2$, so the disc is open.

Similar proof for the disc with radius 1, I understand the property of intersection now, but why is it? The intersection would give you the disc with radius 1, not the washer?

Comment: There are four segments of boundary.  Two are equivalent.  For each segment, pick a point on the boundary.  Is the point in $D$?

Comment: Warning! The set $1<|z|<2$ (ignore the other condition for now) is an annulus (big disk minus small disk).

Comment: @EricTowers: it's not in D, how would you present it?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: wpuld you like to expand the answer? I don't know what an annulus is :(

Comment: I will expand my answer. Meanwhile, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_%28mathematics%29. BTW, what is your $z_0$?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: amy point that is within radius $2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Topology Ia):  The set $D$ is the intersection of three open sets: $1 < |z|$, $|z|<2$, and $-\frac{1}{2} < \Re(z)$.  It is therefore an open set.

(Topology Ib):  The set is the complement of the union of three closed sets: $|z| \leq 1$, $2 \leq |z|$, and $\Re(z) \leq -\frac{1}{2}$.  It is therefore an open set.

(Metric):  Let $z \in D$.  If $1 < |z|$, $|z|<2$, and $-\frac{1}{2} < \Re(z)$, then let $r = \min(|1 - |z||, ||z|-2|, |-\frac{1}{2}-\Re(z)|)$.  Then the ball of radius $r$ centered at $z$ is contained entirely in $D$.  That is, $z$ is in the interior of $D$.

If $1 < |z|$, $|z|<2$, and $-\frac{1}{2} = \Re(z)$, then $z \not \in D$.  For all $\epsilon > 0$, the ball of radius epsilon centered at $z$ contains the interval $z+(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$, which includes points inside and outside $D$, so is on the boundary of $D$.

If $1 < |z|$, $|z|=2$, and $-\frac{1}{2} < \Re(z)$, then $z \not \in D$.  For all $\epsilon > 0$, the ball of radius epsilon centered at $z$ contains the interval $z + \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\arg(z)}(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$, which includes points inside and outside $D$, so is on the boundary of $D$.

If $1 = |z|$, $|z|<2$, and $-\frac{1}{2} < \Re(z)$, then $z \not \in D$.  For all $\epsilon > 0$, the ball of radius epsilon centered at $z$ contains the interval $z + \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\arg(z)}(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$, which includes points inside and outside $D$, so is on the boundary of $D$.

If $1 < |z|$, $|z|=2$, and $-\frac{1}{2} = \Re(z)$, then $z \not \in D$.  For all $\epsilon > 0$, the ball of radius epsilon centered at $z$ contains the interval $z + \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\arg(z)}(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$, which includes points inside and outside $D$, so is on the boundary of $D$.

If $1 = |z|$, $|z|<2$, and $-\frac{1}{2} = \Re(z)$, then $z \not \in D$.  For all $\epsilon > 0$, the ball of radius epsilon centered at $z$ contains the interval $z+(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$, which includes points inside and outside $D$, so is on the boundary of $D$.

If $1 = |z|$ and $|z|=2$, then $z$ does not exist.  Nothing to do here.

If $-\frac{1}{2} = \Re(z)$ and either $1 \geq |z|$ or $|z| \geq 2$, then let $r = \min(|1 - |z||, ||z|-2|)$.  Then the ball of radius $r$ centered at $z$ is contained entirely in the complement of $D$.  That is, $z$ is in the exterior of $D$.

If either $1 = |z|$ or $|z| = 2$, and $-\frac{1}{2} \geq \Re(z)$, then let $r = \min(\max(|1 - |z||, ||z|-2|), |-\frac{1}{2}-\Re(z)|)$.  Then the ball of radius $r$ centered at $z$ is contained entirely in the complement of $D$.  That is, $z$ is in the exterior of $D$.

If $1 \geq |z|$, $|z| \geq 2$, or $-\frac{1}{2} > \Re(z)$, then let $r = \min(|1 - |z||, ||z|-2|, |-\frac{1}{2}-\Re(z)|)$.  Then the ball of radius $r$ centered at $z$ is contained entirely in the complement of $D$.  That is, $z$ is in the exterior of $D$.

Having classified every point of the complex plane as either internal to $D$, on the boundary of $D$ and external to $D$, or separated from $D$ and external to $D$, we have shown that $D$ is open.

(If I missed a case above, it is due to simple omission and one of the arguments made above can be applied to it.)

Answer (score 3):

Is the intersection of three open sets. Each one is the inverse image of a open set by a continuous function.

EDIT: intersection of open sets, the general case.

Let be $O_1,O_2$ two open sets.

If $z_0\in O_1\cap O_2$, then $z_0\in O_1$ and $z_0\in O_2$ by definition, so
$$\exists r_1>0: \ B(z_0,r_1)\subset O_1,\qquad\exists r_2>0: \ B(z_0,r_2)\subset O_2.$$
Take $r=\min(r_1,r_2)$. Then, $B(z_0,r)\subset B(z_0,r_1)\subset O_1$ and $B(z_0,r)\subset B(z_0,r_2)\subset O_2$ , i.e., there is a $z_0$-centered ball $B(z_0,r)\subset O_1\cap O_2$. The extension to any finite intersection of open sets is obvious.

Comment: Yep. My approach exactly.

Comment: @Martin-Blas Perez Pinilla: sorry I do not understand, what guarantees you that if the set is open, the intersection is open. Is there anyway to just show it directly. Please help, I understand the concept, I just don't know how to present this. I have been stuck with this problem for days, and all I get is half answers. It is very frustrating. Is it so wrong for a student who wants to see a nice math proof. It's not like I did not want to think, I am not very good at this, why is that so wrong? This is new to me.

Comment: Finite intersection of open sets = open set is a basic property. Edit the message and write the basic properties of open sets that you *know*. I will expand my answer with the required properties and proofs.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: I edited my answer, I understand the intersection property now, but what about the inverse image?

Comment: @Akaichan, write the definition of continuity with $\epsilon,\delta$.